# Detect character encoding and display accordingly

Tags: php, wordpress, character-encoding

I have inherited a wordpress blog that at some point had the default character encoding changed. This means that new blog posts appear properly but old ones contain various broken characters (they also appear in the admin area).

Is there any way to get around this without manually fixing these characters as there have been about 1000 posts since the change and 3500 from before it.

I have tried a few different ways of converting the data via mysqldump, and converting the database via iconv but had no luck so far.

Comment: What is in --> define('DB_CHARSET', 'Your_charset'); in wp-config.php ? Check table collation in DB fro your wordpress tables

Comment: It's set to "define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');"